# Postgresql regular expressions search word case insensitive and ignore diacritics

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql

In my movements table I have to match all description values that contains the word: `'depósito'`.

It should be case insensitive and also ignores diacritics since can be:

```
Deposito
DEPOSITO
deposito
DEPÓSITO
```

etc, in any part of the `description` sentence.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Case insensivity is easy, by using regex matching operator `~*` (instead of `~`).

When it comes to diacritics, I am unsure that there is a standard way. You would probably need to list the variations.

Also, since you are searching for an entire word, it would be good to use word boundaries to delimit it: `\y`, or `\\y` depending if database setting `standard_conforming_strings` is off.

Consider:

```
description ~* '\ydep[oó]sito\y'
```

Note on diacritics: the documentation mentions [an extension called `unaccent`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html) that can be used to remove accents. Once it is installed and setup, you can do something like:

```
unaccent(description) ~* '\ydeposito\y'
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an elegant way to achieve this in regex (although it is achievable), but you can use both the unaccent function (available from the unaccent extension, and a case-insensitive regex operator.

For example:

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;

SELECT unaccent('depósito') ~* 'deposito';
```

The ~* operator here performs case-insensitive pattern-matching, and unaccent function removes the accents from the original value being searched.  So even if we throw in additional accents and capitalisations, we get the following result:

```
# SELECT unaccent('whatever 123 dépósITo hello') ~* 'DEPOSiTO';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Disclosure: I am an [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://enterprisedb.com/) employee.